# Process Builder throwing an error for null lookup value

Tags: formula, process-builder, visual-workflow, process

I have written the following formula in my process builder

```
[Lead].Source_Opportunity__c != null &&

(ISBLANK(TEXT([Lead].Source_Opportunity__r.Source_details__c)) &&

NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Lead].LeadSource))) &&

ISPICKVAL([Lead].LeadSource ,  'Trig') &&

NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Lead].Source_Opportunity__r.Business_Line__c))) &&

ISPICKVAL([Lead].Source_Opportunity__r.Business_Line__c , 'BL'))
```

Here there is a opportunity related to a lead. Now, if I try to create a new lead, without an opportunity, the Flow is throwing an error despite having the not null check. Is there anything wrong with the formula?

`Source_Opportunity__c` is a lookup

All other fields are picklist

Comment: as others have pointed out, the PB evaluation of conditions doesn't necessarily work from first-to-last with early exit.  Hence, try putting in an initial decision block for null Lead.Opportunity__c (e.g. ISBLANK([Lead].Opportunity__c)  ) and bail out early.

Answer (score 1):

based on [doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315965&type=1&mode=1) you should try `ISBLANK`

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK([Lead].Source_Opportunity__c)),

(ISBLANK(TEXT([Lead].Source_Opportunity__r.Source_details__c)) &&

NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Lead].LeadSource))) &&

ISPICKVAL([Lead].LeadSource , 'Trig') &&

NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT([Lead].Source_Opportunity__r.Business_Line__c))) &&

ISPICKVAL([Lead].Source_Opportunity__r.Business_Line__c , 'BL')))
```